# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Profile'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I'm new to typescript and im getting the error

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Profile'.

on *this.profile* how can I fix this?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Profile } from './../../models/profile';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html',
})
export class ProfilePage {

    profile = {} as Profile;

    constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
      public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    }
    ionViewWillLoad() {
      this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(data => {
          let profileCollection = this.afs.collection('profiles').doc(`${data.uid}`).valueChanges();
          profileCollection.subscribe(profile => this.profile = profile);
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is profile a `class`? It should be an `interface`.

Comment: Aluan, if you are referring to the profile import, it points to a file where the ```interface``` is setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that probably your `Profile` type has mandatory properties. You just have to either make them optional or initialize them to default values. You can’t assign an empty object to a type with properties.

What you can do is also just say `profile: Profile` without initialising it. You’re still enforcing the type. Since you are only assigning it inside the subscribe you don’t need to do the `{}` empty object assignment.

Comment: Ahhh I see I made the properties optional and it worked thank you so much.

Comment: Always glad to help. I’ve edited my answer with a few other options you can have. Please don’t forget to set the answer as checked to help others

Comment: After this I get the error ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Profile'.

If you want to use an assertion like that you need to use the double assertion pattern i.e.

```
profile = {} as any as Profile;
```

## More

- Search `double assertion typescript`
- I wrote about it as well : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html