# Typescript Error: Type {...} is not assignable to type 'User[]'

Tags: angular, typescript

I started playing with Angular 4 and Typescript. I am totally new to Typescript. I saw this question got asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48392672/type-is-not-assignable-to-type-profile), but I was not able to extract the answer to my problem.

```js
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    me: User[];

    ngOnInit() {
       this.me = {
           name: 'Jochen',
           age: 31,
           email: 'mail@web.de',
           address: {
               street: 'Berlinerstraße 24',
               city: 'Berlin',
               state: 'Berlin'
           }
       };
    }
}

interface Address {
    city: string;
    street: string;
    state: string;
}

interface User {
    age: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    address: Address;
}
```

Here is the error I got when running `ng serve`:

```
ERROR in src/app/user/user.component.ts(11,7): error TS2322: Type '{ name: string; age: number; email: string; address: { street: string; city: string; state: strin...' is not assignable to type 'User[]'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type 'User[]'.
```

I wonder how to unserstand the second sentence, where it says `'name' does not exist in type 'User[]'` it exists. Can one help me to understand what I am getting wrong?

Comment: If you meant to create an array of user type, then the syntax (me: User[]) is wrong. Are you looking for this? me: User

Answer (score 4):

`me: User[]` declares the variable `me` as an array of `User` elements, which I suspect is not what you want to do.

The correct syntax should simply be `me: User`